# Create dynamic url android

Tags: java, android

Ok so I'm trying to add 100+ buttons to a listview via CustomAdapter and each button should open a different url. Say my starting url is www.example.com/hi/01.htm and my last url is www.example.com/hi/136.htm . My CustomAdapter moves down the list with the int position. So im thinking it should be something like this:

```
 URL url = new URL("www.example.com/hi/", position);
```

But it doesn't work, plus the htm tag at the end wouldn't appear. Ive searched on google and found lots of things like URi and retrofit but I can't seem to understand how they might work with my specific needs. Any help/tips/advice would be highly apreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `android.net.Uri` instead of `URl` like this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("www.example.com/hi/" + pos + ".htm");
```

Greets

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.format()` to add the variable to the string. In the following example, the `%s` will get replaced with the position variable.

```
URL url = new URL(String.format("http://www.example.com/hi/%s.htm", position));
```

**Note**

You were getting `MalformedURLException` because your example url does not specify the protocol.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String)):

> Throws: MalformedURLException - if no protocol is specified, or an unknown protocol is found, or spec is null.

Comment: I get malformed URL exception

Comment: @DavidGarciaBallester try now.